# How to get Fitbit leaderboard for competition

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, google-sheets-api, fitbit

My [fitbit](http://fitbit.com) friends and are competing for steps and want to display the leaderboard in a web page or google sheet–whichever is easier. [API-Get-Friends-Leaderboard](https://wiki.fitbit.com/display/API/API-Get-Friends-Leaderboard) has the data. What url do I use to make a get request for that data? What's the easiest way to do this? Is seems like I could use [`jQuery.get`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) once I have the right url and auth credentials.

Comment: The documentation you link to has all of this information.  What are you stuck on?

Comment: @Brad what API endpoint or URL do I use to make the request?

Answer (score 1):

The base URL for API requests to FitBit is https://api.fitbit.com/

Here is the general API info from the FitBit wiki: https://wiki.fitbit.com/display/API/Fitbit+Resource+Access+API

You may want to start by registering on Apigee.com and testing the FitBit API via their console.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do competitions between friends or coworkers is to create [FitBit groups](https://www.fitbit.com/groups). Groups can be [public or private](https://www.fitbit.com/groups/create).